# Unable to install packages from RMarkdown

Tags: r, installation, package, r-markdown, knitr

I'm working on a project in RStudio, and all the code runs well. but when I try to get a report in R Makdown, I constantly recieve this error on a chunk which contains installing needed packages:

````
```{r installing packages, include=FALSE}
install.packages("tidyverse")
library(tidyverse)

install.packages("lubridate")
library(lubridate)

install.packages("ggplot2")
library(ggplot2)

install.packages("dplyr")
library(dplyr)
```
````

this is the error message: (line 21-32 means all the mentioned chunk.)

```
Quitting from lines 21-32 (report.Rmd) 
Error in contrib.url(repos, "source") : 
  trying to use CRAN without setting a mirror
Calls: <Anonymous> ... eval_with_user_handlers -> eval -> eval -> install.packages -> contrib.url

Execution halted
```

any recommendation??

I got the error on first chunk, but each chunk runs perfectly with no error when I run them separately.

Comment: The error message indicates that you didn’t select a CRAN mirror. This needs to be done manually, and when running the code non-interactively (such as inside an RMarkdown document), there is no manual selection step, hence this fails. — You can fix this by selecting a mirror. But honestly I recommend against this in general: package installation isn’t something that belongs in a report.

Comment: thanks Konrad, so you mean it's not necessary to have a separate chunk for package installation? in this case, how the other code chunk would be run??  and how to select a CRAN mirror manually?

Comment: Why would you install packages in an rmarkdown script, and not in R directly?

Comment: well, the project is about a case study of a DATA ANALYTICS course, and I have to explain every thing from the scratch. uploading 12 large files, cleaning the data, adding needed columns to the data frame, visualizing and other things. I did the code in R, but for having a final report, I need to include everything in R Markdown.

Comment: Well `library` call to a specific package should convey the message that you have already installed the package in your system. But if you still need to show the installation command in your report,  you can add them as a commented code like `#install.packages("dplyr")` in the RMD file. Because again, Its a very bad idea to include installation code in the rmd file and strongly recommended against.

Comment: And note that installing `tidyverse` and library call to it covers the installation and library call of `lubridate`, `dplyr`, `ggplot2`.

Comment: You can use `requireNamespace` to check if a required package is installed and terminate the kintting of the report (with `knit_exit()`) if it isn't. For what it is worth, if I were your tutor, I would mark you down heavily for including any call to `install.packages()` in a report script.  Doing so, IMHO, demonstates a fundamental lack of understanding of R's underlying architecture.

Comment: @Limey, I'd say that's a bit harsh.  Base R doesn't have a clean way to say:  "This report needs packages x, y, and z, but they are not installed.  Please install them before processing it."  You can put that together yourself, but saying that not doing so "reflects a fundamental lack of understanding" suggests that R Core lacks understanding too, and that's clearly not true.

Comment: @Limey I’m not sure I understand the purpose of your `requireNamespace` suggestion: using `library` will have the same effect without the need for a manual check or call to `knit_exit`.

Comment: @user2554330 The base R way of saying that is … `library`. But I agree that there’s certainly room for improvement here. At the time of writing, the best (non-base R) way to express this is via an ‘renv’ lockfile. This honestly isn’t great but better than explicitly installing packages in a report. At any rate I don’t think this warrants marking down the report.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, the disadvantage of most base R methods is that they work on one package at a time.  If the report needs 3 packages, it's tedious to have it fail 3 times before you finally know what to install.  The advantage of approaches using `requireNamespace` is that they can be written to check all requirements before finally failing.  The advantage of `knit_exit` is mainly in packages:  CRAN doesn't like it if your package fails when Suggested dependencies are missing.  `knit_exit` lets it exit gracefully.

Comment: @user2554330 Yeah, I’m aware. Hence my mention of ‘renv’.

Comment: @KonradRudolph as I'm sure you know, `library("badLibrary")` throws an exception.  `requireNamespace("badLibrary")` returns `FALSE`, so you can check for the installation of a package without needing to resort to `tryCatch` or similar.  I agree, both approaches need a manual check, but `requireNamespace` seems both simpler and less reliant on side effects.

Comment: @Limey But you want to stop knitting either way so you *don’t* need (and shouldn’t use!) `tryCatch` around the `library` call. The default behaviour is already what you want, there is *no* manual check required.